# Can't plot when using dynamic linewidth

Tags: plot, dynamic, pine-script, linewidth

I am using version3. It just won´t work:

```
width =  (RMI > 86) ? 1 : 4
plot(RMI, title="RMI", linewidth=width, color=col, transp=0)
```

error message is something like
line 71: Cannot call `plot` with arguments...

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by using two plots and by alternating their color/transparency according to the argument. The linewidth argument needs to be either an explicitly defined integer, ie `linewidth = 4` or obtain from an input variable ie `width = input(4)`

```
plot(RMI, title = "RMI thin",   linewidth = 1, color = RMI >= 86 ? col : #00000000, transp = 0)
plot(RMI, title = "RMI thick",  linewidth = 4, color = RMI > 86 ? #00000000 : col, transp = 0)
```